# Copy stderr to both file and terminal in POSIX sh

Tags: shell, sh, stderr, io-redirection

Writing a shell script within AWS DataPipeline that connects to a relational database, and the exit code is 0 even for SQL errors, so I need to capture + redirect stderr.

I'm redirecting stderr to another file to check for its contents, but still want stderr to be populated. The reason is that DataPipeline captures all the stderr and stdout and puts them all into 1 log. It's not capturing the stderr from the failed sql command because of the redirection. Is there a way to still have stderr populated? What I currently have is:

```
/bin/snowsql -f /home/scripts/dev/dev.sql 2> /home/scripts/dev/stderr.txt
```

Comment: Hmm. We've got lots of duplicates for this asking how to redirect *both* stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot shorter in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh

...yourcommand... 2> >(tee stderr.text >&2)
```

---

In a POSIX-compliant manner, it looks more like:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -f -- "stderr_and_logfile.$$"
mkfifo -- "stderr_and_logfile.$$" || exit
tee stderr.txt <"stderr_and_logfile.$$" >&2 &

/bin/snowsql -f /home/scripts/dev/dev.sql 2>"stderr_and_logfile.$$"; retval=$?

rm -f -- "stderr_and_logfile.$$"
exit "$retval" # so "rm" doesn't cause the exit status of snowsql to be discarded
```

Comment: Thanks, looking at the link in your above comment, I ended up changing the script to `/bin/snowsql -f /home/scripts/dev/dev.sql 2> >(tee /home/ubuntu/scripts/dev/stderr.txt >&2)` but am getting an error of `redirection unexpected`.

Comment: Looks like your shell is `sh`, not `bash`. Bash syntax is only guaranteed to be available with `bash yourscript`, not `sh yourscript`; even when the two commands refer to the same executable on-disk, bash runs in POSIX compatibility mode when started under the name `sh`.

Comment: Ah - so it worked when I designated the bash shebang, but is there a shell equivalent for `tee`? All my searches keep showing to use `tee` and I can't seem to know the right correct question to ask for this to work without bash

Comment: `tee` isn't the part that's bash-only, it's the `>()` process-substitution syntax. And yes, you can do that in a POSIX-compliant way, it's just wordier. Tag your question `sh`, not `bash`, when asking about it.